# How to prevent svg from pushing the content to the top?

Tags: css, svg, layout

[image]

https://codepen.io/diana-larussa/pen/OJgjLqj
the code looks basically like that:

```
contact-section
svg-container
footer
```

I think the image is pretty self-explanatory... I also tried to solve it by using :before but it just doesn't work... Please help.

Comment: you can use your `SVG` as background image.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the svg container from the document flow (so that it can't be pushed by the form) and position it at the top relative to a parent element.

First enclose both elements in a common parent:

```
<div class="main-wrapper">
    <div class="main-container"></div>
    <div class="svg-container"></svg>
</div>
```

Set the svg container to be absolutely positioned (absolutely relative to its parent, that's why main-wrapper has `position:relative`).

```
.main-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main-container {
    /* ... */
    position: relative; /* necessary for z-index */
    z-index: 1; /* keep the content above svg-container */
}
.svg-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```